# Is there a way for a video to trigger an HTTP POST event (or other event)

Tags: android, triggers, http-post, video-streaming, html5-video

I really don't know what I'm asking here but I'm going to try my best.

I want to make a video that will run on an android box in our office.

We are a company that installs and programs home automation systems. I want to make a demo video that will be shown to clients. The video will say something like "this is how lighting control works" and the office will then turn lights on and off. "This is multi-room audio, you can listen to one thing here" and then speakers will switch off in one room, on in the next room "or listen to something else in here at a different volume" the speakers will then switch back to the theatre demo room. "We can also control the shades" shades will move up and down. The problem is I have to script things based on delays...that's fine if a client watches the entire video, but I want them to be able to pause and ask questions.

My question is can I trigger an HTTP post or another networked trigger from the android box to an onsite web server or the actual automation controller? Is this possible, when the video reaches 1:12 do POST "trigger theatre lights" I can make the action work on my automation system I just need to make a video trigger events at specific times...

Comment: Video cannot make a http request, but your video player or your custom video player make a request when you want during video plays.. or you can do it with other with interactive tools, like unity3d, android studio....

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us which videoplayer you use (or on which OS it runs) but most of them should have some sort of progress listener that you can set. The listener will be called every x seconds telling you the current progress of the video in playback. 
Example:

```
videoPlayer.setOnProgressListener(new ProgressListener {
   void onProgress(Long position){

   }
})
```

Should your videoplayer not have such a progress listener within it's API, it will at least have a method to retrieve the current playpack position. 
You could then actively ask for the current playback position every x seconds and do all your funky home automation stuff based on the current video playback position.